# minikube/k8s/kubectl "failed to watch file [ ... ]: no space left on device"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm fairly new to k8s and minikube, and could use help understanding the frequent-but-not-ubiquitous error I get when running `kubectl logs -f <POD NAME>`

I get this, sometimes, and unpredictably, on pods in my own namespace, and in `kube-system`, e.g. when trying to tail the ingress controller logs. There is no apparent error in the pods themselves, and the output of the `kubectl logs` command contains normal-looking log lines right up to, e.g. `failed to watch file "/var/log/pods/kube-system_nginx-ingress-controller-586cdc477c-95pgh_4b8310a4-5f9b-11e9-9666-0800270e7244/nginx-ingress-controller/1.log": no space left on device$`

What's the ultimate source of this, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like the node has run out of inotify watches.

You can check or set the number of available watches using the sysctl `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` on each Kubernetes [node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/).

You will probably find it has been set to some ridiculously low number; by default it is autotuned based on the amount of memory the system has.

```
[root@small ~]# sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 8192

[root@large ~]# sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1048576
```

Whatever the amount is currently, double it until the problem stops occurring.

(Use `minikube ssh` to access a Minikube node.)

Comment: hey thanks! for those like me, new to k8s `sysctl` the command to set it is `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576`